# Sync webserver database in android sqlitr database

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to sync those 2 database?
While i'm offline i'll use my android sqlite database, and while i'm online my database in android will be updated  base on the database on webserver.

Comment: Absolutely. You just have to write the code to do it. You'll want to look into using Android's sync adapter framework. If you are asking if there's something that'll do the work for you, no, not in Android proper. It's sort of a hard problem ... mapping web responses to databases, tracking modification times, change tokens, etc.

Comment: So this sync adapter framework can run in backround? Thank you! :)

Comment: If you're willing to use NoSQL, [Couchbase Sync + Couchbase Lite](http://www.couchbase.com/use-cases/mobile-applications) handles this for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have too many options to do that.You need to consider when you are going to update your local db depending on remote.simply you can add a refresh button to check if any updates in remote to synch your local db.